# Android: How do I find the list of calls made to a particular contact?

Tags: android, android-contacts, phone-call, calllog

Given a contact, or a contact ID, in android, how do I get the list of calls made to or from that contact?  Like the call log, but filtered to just one individual (with the possibility of multiple phone numbers, of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you don't. There is no strict relational tie between the `CallLog` and the `ContactsContract` content providers.

The `CallLog` does cache the display name of the caller, if that caller was a contact, and you can try to look that up, but I would expect that to be moderately unreliable, because while the `ContactsContract` data may change, the `CallLog` data will not.

Comment: Thanks, that's how it was looking to me.  I could also query by phone number, but they're stored in strange ways (with hyphens in one table, without, in the other; in some tables, stored in reversed-digit form).  Messy!